# How to back up mssql database using java?

Tags: java

I am currently using Mssql2000. How can I back up this database using java application? is it possible?

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: he just wants to run the back up command from java program rather than DB console , right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use jdbc to run a backup database script such...

```
BACKUP DATABASE 'databaseOfNames' TO DISK = 'c:\myFile'
```

So you'd do something like...

```
 try (
         // Step 1: Allocate a database "Connection" object
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/ebookshop", "myuser", "password"); // MySQL

         // Step 2: Allocate a "Statement" object in the Connection
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      ) {
         String strSelect = "BACKUP DATABASE 'databaseOfNames' TO DISK = 'c:\myFile' ";
         ResultSet rset = stmt.execute(strSelect);
      }
```

It should be noted this uses the new JDK7 try-with-resources code, so it'll automatically close the resources.

Comment: Where to mention dbUserName and passWord ?

Comment: Within jdbc connection string, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: can u please tell how to backup oracle database?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code only if you are accessing DB in local.

```
 public boolean backupDB(String dbName, String path) {
    String executeCmd = "BACKUP DATABASE '"+ dbName +"' TO DISK = '"+ path +"' ";
    Process runtimeProcess;
    try {

        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

For more on SQL Backup refer this [URL](http://www.howtogeek.com/51788/how-to-backup-sql-databases-to-a-network-share/)